# hMailServer - can send from local PC, but not from remote client

Tags: smtp, connection

I set up a hMailServer. I am able to send e-mails from any computer connected to the local network, but when I try to connect from another IP, the server does not accept connection.

I tried both Relayer and without Relayer, but in both scenarios, external connections are not working.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: may be check firewalls, allowed IPs

Comment: firewall exceptions added both for in and outcoming traffic for ports 25 and 587, all IPs allowed. 

just cannot connect to smtp when I am traveling. have to go through the remote desktop to send mails from the server.